# Получить Map из json, с использованием GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

нужно получить `Map` из json, есть:
**json**

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"aaa",
    "operations":[
        {
            "type":"add",
            "value":"1"
        },
        {
            "type":"delete",
            "value":"2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**java**

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Operations> operations;

    public User(int id, String name, Operations operations) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.operations = this.operations;
    }    
    // geters and seters    
}
public class Operations {
    private String type;
    private String value;

    public Operations(String type, String value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
        // geters and seters
}
```

**gson**

```
 // String userData = ...
User user = gson.fromJson(userData, User.class);
```

Как сделать, чтобы в `user` вместо `List` был `Map` и можно было получить `operations` по ключу, например `user.getOperations.get("add");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вижу два варианта.

Первый - сделать вручную, например так:

```
public class User {
    ...
    private List<Operations> operations;
    private Map<String, String> opMap;
    ...
    public Map<String, String> getOperations() {
        if (opMap == null) {
            //TODO создаём карту и перекладываем из списка
        }
        return opMap;
    }
}
```

Второй - заменяем список на карту в User, добавляем кастомный десериализатор для User:

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
                            JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        User user = new User();
        JsonObject ob = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        user.setId(ob.getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsInt());
        user.setName(ob.getAsJsonPrimitive("name").getAsString());
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        JsonArray arr = ob.getAsJsonArray("operations");
        for (JsonElement e: arr) {
            map.put(e.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("type").getAsString(),
                    e.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("value").getAsString());
        }
        user.setOperations(map);
        return user;
    }
}
```

и потом десериализуем так:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer())
        .create();
User user = gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
```

Comment: Спасибо! все получилось.